# One or more http request headers was not valid for the SOAP request

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to connect my Java application with the Channel Advisor API and I get this error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. One or more http request headers was not valid for the SOAP request. </faultstring>
            <detail/>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my request:

```
String requestURL = "https://api.channeladvisor.com/ChannelAdvisorAPI/v7/InventoryService.asmx";
String request = 
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'   xmlns:web='http://api.channeladvisor.com/webservices/'>"+
   "<soapenv:Header>"+
      "<web:APICredentials>"+
         "<!--Optional:-->"+
         "<web:DeveloperKey>XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX</web:DeveloperKey>"+
         "<!--Optional:-->"+
         "<web:Password>XXXXXXXXXX</web:Password>"+
      "</web:APICredentials>"+
   "</soapenv:Header>"+
   "<soapenv:Body>"+
      "<web:GetInventoryQuantity>"+
         "<web:accountID>XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</web:accountID>"+
         "<web:sku>XXXXXX-XX-XXX</web:sku>"+
      "</web:GetInventoryQuantity>"+
   "</soapenv:Body>"+
"</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

The strange thing is that if I try the same request with SoapUI I get back a successful response.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to address the actual message the web service is returning (emphasis mine)?

> Server was unable to process request. One or more **http request headers** was not valid for the SOAP request

If it works from SoapUI then it means you are not sending a proper request from your Java application. SoapUI records some [logs](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/main-window.html#logs) when it performs the request. You can look at he HTTP logs and see what headers it sends.

My guess is you are either missing the `SOAPAction` or the `Content-Type`. Start adding the headers one by one and see when the web service stops complaining.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I found my error and I solved this. The problem was the SOAPAction. I fixed this adding this line:
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "urlToRequestedAction");